# How to get the ID of the cell that currently has focus in MUI Data Grid?

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

MUI Data Grid allows to mouse-click on a cell to put it in focus, to use the keyboard arrows to shift which cell is focused, and to set the focused cell manually.

I can't however, figure out how to find out which cell is currently focused at any given time.

Can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can extend the DataGrid with additional row and cell hooks.
Also, it appears that when the DOM is created, the `row id` is saved as a `data-id` attribute, and the `row field` is saved as a `data-field` attribute, so you can access them like so:

```jsx
<DataGrid
slotProps={{
          row: {
            onFocus: (event: any) => {
              const newVal = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');
            },
          },
          cell: {
            onFocus: (event: any) => {
              const newVal = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-field');
            },
          }
        }}
/>
```

The conjunction of a row id and a cell field pin-point the specific cell that is selected.